# why am I having this error: Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: php, apache

I am new in apache server. Basically I have a production server. There is a website working the server. I have added new file `index.php` in the root (`/var/www/html`) containing

```
<?php
   echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

But when ever I try `xx.xx.xx.xx/index.php`, I allways have error message saying:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

I have create a file  httpd.conf containing:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

But still not working.

```
php version is 5.6 
apache version is 2.4.18
```

when I tried `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` it works find.

How can I allow to access my server with ip address like xx.xx.xx.xx/index.php ?

Comment: Do you have a `.htaccess` in the directory? Does the webserver owner have enough permissions for the folder?

Comment: @modsfabio yess I have .htaccess file containing `<Files>Options -Indexes IndexIgnore * </Filles>`

Comment: Try it without the `.htaccess`

Comment: @modsfabio thank for your answer. I have rename my .htaccess to back.htaccess.  I still having the same error. Do I have to restart my apache ?

Comment: You don't have to restart it if you change/remove the `.htaccess`. Well, does the webserver owner have enough premissions for that folder?

Comment: what is your apache version?

Comment: @modsfabio my apache version is 2.4

Comment: But the webserver is running on a different user, at least it should. By default the user is `www-data`. Please check that

Comment: @modsfabio /var/www/http  is owned by www-data ? what should I check please ?

Comment: If the user has all permissions for that folder

Comment: @modsfabio www-data has all permission on this http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this (if not already present) in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` :

```
<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And make sure your folder and its content `/var/www/html` belongs to www-data :

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/html
sudo chmod 770 -r /var/www/html
```